# Move child window in side parent window in wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.Left < this.Owner.Left)
        this.Left = this.Owner.Left;

    if (this.Top < this.Owner.Top)
        this.Top = this.Owner.Top;

}
```

As you can see the code above written, but I am not able to restrict the window while moving 
at the bottom and right of Desktop. Because I am not finding any attribute for that.

Like  this.Right
      or this.Bottom

Please suggest if Any one has implemented the same.

Thanks
Madhav

Answer (score 0):

this.Right would be:

```
this.Left + this.Width
```

this.Bottom is:

```
this.Top + this.Height
```

So the lines of code that are equivalent to what you have written above, but for right and bottom would be:

```
if (this.Left + this.Width > this.Owner.Left + this.Owner.Width)
    this.Left = this.Owner.Left + this.Owner.Width - this.Width;

if (this.Top + this.Height > this.Owner.Top + this.Owner.Height)
    this.Top = this.Owner.Top + this.Owner.Height - this.Height;
```